# NetSuite Summary Saved Search to Combine Text from Each Detail Row

Tags: netsuite, saved-searches

I'm trying to create a summary saved search so that for each summarized row, text from each line in the detailed/non-summarized rows is combined.

For example, the summary view would include a list of Bill Payment transactions with one Bill Payment on each row.  Then a Formula (Text) column would combine the Document Number of each bill paid by that Bill Payment transaction.

### Example Summary Results

```
Bill_Payment_#    Bills_Paid 
10501             7981, 7984
10502             CD5029, CD5030, CD5031, CD5032
10503             INV03683
```

In this example, Bill Payment 10501 paid two bills and those are combined into a single text field.  Bill Payment 10502 paid four bills and Bill Payment 10503 paid one.

I am quite familiar with NetSuite saved searches including custom formulas, but I'm not sure where to start with this.  Any assistance or pointers would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Formula (Text)` column, and use the `NS_CONCAT` function to give you this result.

### Example:

#### Filters:

Type = Bill Payment
Date = within this year
Main Line = False

#### Columns:

Date - (Group)
Document Number - (Group)
Name - (Group)
Formula (Text) - (Minimum) *Formula = `NS_CONCAT({appliedtotransaction})`*

---

This `Formula (Text)` column gives a result with all the applied to transactions concatenated with commas between.

EG: Bill #2405884,Bill #2430016,Bill #2429826,Bill #2429706

To get a nicer layout, you can wrap the formula above in a `REPLACE` function like `REPLACE(NS_CONCAT({appliedtotransaction}), ',', ' | ')`

This would return: Bill #2405884 | Bill #2430016 | Bill #2429826 | Bill #2429706